# Is there a better way to check if a variable exists in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Currently I am (in many places in a project) checking to see if data exists at one object's root level, just to see if the next level exists, just to see the next and so on.

This might look something like this:

```
let name = display.data ? display.data ? data.name.bio ? data.name.bio.details ? :"Name N/A" : "Name N/A" : "Name N/A" : "Name N/A"
```

Instead of checking it this way, is there a way to make a call directly to `data.name.bio.details` that doesn't throw an error but silently falls back to being undefined?

E.g. if I call `data.name.bio.details` and `data.name.bio` doesn't exist, I'll get an error saying that and it's not so silent.

Could I do something like this, that wouldn't scream bloody murder when .bio doesn't exist?:

```
var name = data.name.bio.details || "Name N/A"
```

Hope this makes sense, not sure if there's a better approach!

Comment: If the Object exists and it's an object property, you can do like `if(obj.prop === undefined){ /* not defined */}`. You can also simply test for `=== undefined` if the var is an argument or is declared with `var`, `let`, or `const`. If there is no declaration whatsoever you should do like `if(typeof yourVar === 'undefined'){ /* not defined */ }`. That last way works under all circumstances. Note, of course, that if your object is not defined then `if(typeof obj.prop === 'undefined'){}` would throw undefined error on the obj.

Answer (score 4):

Use logical AND `&&` and OR `||`:

```
var name = data && data.name && data.name.bio && data.name.bio.details || "Name N/A";
```

You could also use try/catch if you're not sure if `data` is defined- the above will throw a ReferenceError if `data` isn't defined:

```
try {
  var name = data.name.bios.details;
} catch(e) {
  var name = "Name N/A";
}
```

Comment: Yeah I guess this gets right of a bunch of the fallback/false cases

Comment: Heads up, this requires data to be at least defined.

Comment: Fixed @Matthew.

Comment: It works, but the try-catch is an intensive process. Honestly, I would be curious to benchmark using the try-catch against the in-line check and see the differences.

Comment: "Intensive" is only relative. Won't matter for a low number of failure cases. Most micro-benchmarks (ie. 1,000,000 attempts) will swamp with worst-case scenarios that have no practical bearing in many real life scenarios: eg. if such an exception guard is used a few times (or even on a few hundred times..) per app, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: It shouldn't, but I also don't agree to use a try-catch for a simple null check in this case. It just seems lazy to me (Personal opinion).

Comment: That's a different argument.

Comment: The `AND` / `OR` approach isn't really any better than the original solution in the question

Answer (score 1):

If you're transpiling your code, check out [tc39/proposal-optional-chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).

There's a Babel Plugin that will handle it for you.

```
var name = data?.name?.bio?.details || "Name N/A"
```

Obviously this won't work as-is, yet, but worth considering if you are already using Babel (or similar)!

Comment: I only wish this was possible in standard JS. I miss my nullables from C#

Comment: We'll get there one day pal. This will almost certainly become standard, it's just gonna take some time...

Comment: this is so nice, wish list for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, mine would be similar to the other, but I would prefer this route.

EDIT:

I was thinking of another way to not have it so long-winded, I arrived this.

```
((typeof data != 'undefined') ? data.name && data.name.bio && data.name.bio.details && data.name.bio.details || "Name NA" : "Name NA")
```

It'll perform a null check against data and then it'll just eval using the other method (I honestly forget what it is called) and then it'll return the appropriate value.

EDIT: Fixed issue where it would fail in Edge. Tested in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox. Also removed the first method.

Comment: Could start with `x && x.y && x.y.z..`: the ternary location looks of little value: maybe if it was *around* the conditions? Such will "potentially fail" for the edge-case of `x && x.str && x.str.length` .. just to keep truthiness rules around.

Comment: You are right. I have never realized that before. How would one check on Edge to see if a variable is null or undefined? I have done all the standard checks and each of them came back with a fail. Please tell me it isn't a try-catch.

EDIT: Found it.

Answer (score 0):

!!yourVar 
above will check yourVar is not empty, not undefined, not null etc...

Comment: Will that scream if for example bio doesn't exist in: !!data.name.bio.details?